# grep -w finds partial match in words with non-latin letters

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to grep for the exact match of "er", but grep -w finds a partial match in words with non-Latin letters such as "ß" in addition to the exact match. The command below finds "er" in "großer", and "weißer". The expected behavior is that grep only finds the exact match of "er" in the string below with no partial matches.

```
echo "großer, Teller, der, er, weißer" | grep -w "er"
```

I also tried exporting `LC_ALL=C`, but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: What does `echo "großer, Teller, der, er, weißer" | grep -ow "er"` output for you?

Comment: To be clear you mean a non-Latin (aka non-ASCII) _letter_, not a special character (which is punctuation, math symbols, and such). Using C locale goes in the wrong direction; that does not have any non-Latin letters. In a Unicode locale what you have should work and does for me. In case you don't realize, `grep` by default outputs the whole line if there is a match anywhere in the line; if you want to output only the _part_ (or parts) of the line that match the regexp, add `-o`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a GNU `grep`, you can use

```
grep -oP "(*UCP)\ber\b"
grep -P "(*UCP)\ber\b"
```

The `(*UCP)` PCRE verb will make `\b`, word boundary pattern, fully Unicode-aware.

With `pcregrep`, you can also use this approach, but you need to specify the `-u` option:

```sh
pcregrep -ou '(*UCP)\ber\b'
pcregrep -u '(*UCP)\ber\b'
```

> `-u, --utf-8                  use UTF-8 mode`

The `o` option is used to extract matches rather than printing the whole line where the match was found.

Comment: How can I combine ```grep -P "(*UCP)\ber\b``` with patterns obtained from a FILE (one pattern per line)?

Comment: @Marc : `grep -P -f <(sed 's/.*/(*UCP)\\b&\\b/' patterns.txt) foo.txt`

Comment: @Shawn The command above fails, since the -P option only supports a single pattern.

Comment: @Marc `pcregrep` seems to work with list of patterns, `pcregrep -uf <(sed 's/.*/(*UCP)\\b&\\b/' patterns.txt) foo.txt`